# Does the css background-size not work in FF 3.6.x?

Tags: css, firefox, firefox3.6

Checkout my site in FF 3.6:

[www.compversions.com](http://www.compversions.com) and look at it in every other newer browser (FF4+, Chrome latest builds, IE9, etc.) and they all look fine.

In ff 3.6, the logo and the chameleon are too big.

What's the fix here, or do I need to clear my cache or something because you guys don't see any problems in your ff 3.6?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [When can I use](http://caniuse.com/#search=background-size), you need to prefix the `background-size` property with `-moz-` in Firefox 3.6:

```
-moz-background-size: <your settings>;
background-size: <your settings>;
```

Make sure you put `background-size` last so it overrides the vendor-specific prefix.

Comment: Just tried that and it doesn't work. Still showing up in FF 3.6 as looking weird. Just pushed those changes. Do you see it?

Comment: Actually, that did work. I left off a `;`. My bad :|

Thanks!!

Comment: Man, you just saved my bacon. Out of all the CSS attributes, I thought for sure this wouldn't need a vendor prefix. Thanks again.